# How to create a script to automate click on a button/link on multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screenshot

I have button/link that takes a screenshot when clicked.  How can I automate this to click the link on all pages to take the screenshot by a script so I can have all screenshots available.  Currently using webshot gem to capture the image.

```
<%= link_to 'Take Screenshot', capture_image_account_site_path(@account, @site), method: :post, data: { disable_with: 'Processing...', id:'screenshot' } %>


def capture_image
   @site = Site.find(params[:id])
   @ws                   = Webshot::Screenshot.instance if @site.primary?
   @url                  = @site.website
   @ws_image             = @ws.capture strip_url(@site.website), "#{Rails.root}/public/images/screenshots/#{@site.id}.png", width:300, height:180, timeout:3
   redirect_to(account_site_url(@account, @site, view: 'active'))
end
```

Was thinking about creating a rake but I have never created one before.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to click on a link on a webpage?  Have you tried a webdriver-based tool (e.g. selenium)?

Comment: I have a link on my view that will take a screenshot.  I am just trying to figure out a ruby way to click that link so all the screenshots will be taken.

Comment: @stooky so you want to start on a page and then click all of the links that you can find and screen shot each?

Comment: Yes I would like to just have all screenshots taken initially and users can delete or retake later if they like.